# Text from UILabel is not added to separate view controller array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a `NSMutableArray` and I would like to add values that are inputed into a `UILabel` in a subclassed `UIAlertView` that allows me to add subviews. The problem is that I have though is that the `UIViewController` that I have to keep track of the score isn't receiving the inputed values since it is constantly returning a value of Nil.

Within the `UIAlertVIew` controller I use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification. The UIViewController that holds the score has a listener that checks for the update.

Here is the code for the method that is called when the `IViewController` hears the notification

```
-(void)doneButtonPressed{
    i++;
    // g2RowIndex ++;
    j = i -2;
    k = i-3;
    CustomUiAlertView *customAlertView;
    NSLog(@"%@", customAlertView.p1G1ScoreLabel.text);

}
```

The scoreLabel belongs to the subclassed `UIViewController`. I am wondering how to get the inputed values within the `UILabel` to be placed in the `scoreArray` within the socreViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alloc/init the CustomUiAlertView.

Comment: You are correct, I changed the way in which the CustomUIAlertVIew is declared and allocated and by doing so I fixed the problem.